# PHP - Regular Expressions - Match regexp without including the same regexp multiple times

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Using `PHP`, I have the folloowing code:

```
$text = '[text 1] highlight("ABC DEF") [text 2] highlight("GHI JKL") [text 3] [text 4]';
```

Then I want to `catch` the following `groups`:

```
group 1: highlight("ABC DEF") [text 2]
group 2: highlight("GHI JKL") [text 3] [text 4]
```

I tried the following:

```
preg_match_all('/highlight.*/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

but I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => highlight("ABC DEF") [text 2] highlight("GHI JKL") [text 3] [text 4]
        )

)
```

But that's not what I want because it is all together.

I also tried:

```
preg_match_all('/highlight/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

but I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => highlight
            [1] => highlight
        )

)
```

And that's not what I want neither.

Any idea what `regexp` to use in order to get the `groups` I mentioned `above`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$matches = array();

preg_match_all("/highlight\([^)]*\) .*?(?= highlight|$)/", '[text 1] highlight("ABC DEF") [text 2] highlight("GHI JKL") [text 3] [text 4]', $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

For explanations:

https://regex101.com/r/8ZQjNr/5

Comment: A faster equivalent of the same regex is [`highlight\([^)]*\)[^h]*(?:h(?!ighlight\([^)]*\))[^h]*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/IuMBxA/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Great job there!:)

Comment: In PCRE, lazy dot matching patterns are better unrolled. As a bonus, this will match across newlines, without the DOTALL modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Preg_split?

```
preg_split("/(highlight)/", $input_line);
```

Try it here:  http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/hYr

With PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE option it will keep highlight in the string

Comment: Doesn't provide the output he wants.

Comment: He has not showed what he wants, only what he wants to capute. If you make a regex with "highlight", you know what is missing. But sure, you can use the option `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` to keep the delimiter